# dc.js, prevent pie chart external label overlap

Tags: dc.js, dc.leaflet.js

I am not able to show labels properly for the cases where group values are very close together so the labels tend to overlap. I have tried minAngleForLabel. What else can be done here? The code for the pie chart is:

```
  var types = xf.dimension(function(d) { return d.txntype; });
  var typesSum = types.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.txnamount; });
  var pieChart = dc.pieChart("#pie-row-chart",groupname)
      .width(370)
      .height(309)
      .slicesCap(4)
      .innerRadius(70)
      .colors(d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeSet1))
      .drawPaths(true)
      .externalRadiusPadding(60)
      .minAngleForLabel(5)
      .externalLabels(40)
      .dimension(types)
      .group(typesSum)
      .title(function(d) {
          return d.key + ': ' +  Math.round((d.value * 100)/100) + ' BDT';
      })
      .on('pretransition', function(pieChart) {
          pieChart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
              return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
          })
      });
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag for questions about the charting library. [dc] is a classic unix calculator utility.

Comment: Hmm, that setting should actually remove all the labels (!), since `minAngleForLabel` is specified in radians... I missed this question because of the wrong tag, did you figure it out yet?

Comment: You're right Gordon. But the labels are still there! I didn't solve it yet unfortunately. I can't figure out why the minAngleForLabel doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what is happening is that the chart set the label to the empty string when there is no data, and then you are setting it back in your `pretransition` handler.

The chart has

```
function sliceTooSmall (d) {
    var angle = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle);
    return isNaN(angle) || angle < _minAngleForLabel;
}
```

[source](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/075213030ebb778daa2f2ff13aab0ed7590fb9ac/src/pie-chart.js)

```
    labels
        .text(function (d) {
            var data = d.data;
            if ((sliceHasNoData(data) || sliceTooSmall(d)) && !isSelectedSlice(d)) {
                return '';
            }
            return _chart.label()(d.data);
    });
```

[source](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/075213030ebb778daa2f2ff13aab0ed7590fb9ac/src/pie-chart.js#L172-L179)

You can detect in your `pretransition` handler if the chart has decided not to display text, with `d3.select(this).text()`:

```
  .on('pretransition', function(pieChart) {
      pieChart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
          return d3.select(this).text() && (d.data.key + ' ' + 
            dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) /
            (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%');
      })
  });
```

Once you do that, you'll probably want to set `minAngleForLabel` a bit lower, since it's specified in radians.

Comment: Solved! Thank you Gordon!

Comment: Thanks Gordon! adding "d3.select(this).text() && " to return solved my issue.